# Appach Guacomole JS RDP window scaling

Tags: javascript, guacamole

I'm using javascript Apache Guacamole Client on my website for RDP control.
I've faced a problem - on window resize display wasn't resized.
I've tried to use "scale" method of Guacamole Display:

```
guac = new Guacamole.Client(tunnel);
...
guac.getDisplay().scale(myScale);
```

This method changes display size. However when the resize is performed, mouse coordinates are kept as they were on client. So mouse pointer on client and on web screen are not matched.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The **Fix** is to apply scaling to mouse coordinates too:

> ```
>     let scale = 1;
>     $(document).ready(function ($) {
>
>         $(window).resize(function () {
>            nsZoomZoom();
>         });
>
>         //Get screen resolution.
>         origHeigth = window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio;
>         origWidth = window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio;
>
>         nsZoomZoom();
>
>         function nsZoomZoom() {
>             //Calculating scalse
>             let htmlWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
>             var htmlHeigth = $(window).height();
>             var xscale = htmlWidth / origWidth;
>             var yscale = htmlHeigth / origHeigth;
>             //This is done to handle both X and Y axis slacing
>             scale = Math.min(xscale, yscale);
>             //Add 10% to scale because window always less than screen resolution
>             scale += scale / 10;
>             //Change Cuacamole Display scale
>             guac.getDisplay().scale(scale);  
>         }
>     });
>
>         ...   
>         guac = new Guacamole.Client(tunnel);
>
>         const guacEl = guac.getDisplay().getElement();
>         rootEl.appendChild(guacEl);
>
>         mouse = new Guacamole.Mouse(guacEl);
>         mouse.onmousedown = mouse.onmouseup = (state) => guac.sendMouseState(state); 
>         //The fix is here
>         mouse.onmousemove = (state) => {
>             updateMouseState(state);
>         }; 
>
>    //Handle mouse coordinates scaling         
>     let updateMouseState = (mouseState) => {
>         mouseState.y =  mouseState.y / scale;
>         mouseState.x =  mouseState.x / scale;
>         guac.sendMouseState(mouseState);
>     }
> ```

I hope it'll help someone.

Answer (score 0):

kban,When drag and drop browser’s right-down corner,gua display zone will left a blank(down or right direction),this seems only executing browser’s guacamole js's scale function,how to solute this problem ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aKPo.jpg)